# How to cache this mysql query for the make and model of a vehicle?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have some php code that queries a mysql database of year makes and models. The year is hard coded in the php as it is a small amount of data. However the make and model are queried from the database based on the previous choices. IE: Selecting 2012 allows the makes of cars only made in 2012 and then after selecting the make it lists the models made by the chosen make. Below is the code I have that creates the query to select the make. How can I cache this after it is called for a set amount of time to speed up subsequent queries? Or is it even possible?

I should mention that my hosting provider doesn't allow me to turn caching on for mysql. That is why I would like to try it in php.

```
$year = $_POST['year'];     // get the year from post - sent via ajax

$vehmakes = $cl->getmakes($year);
$output = '<option value="">-- All Makes --</option>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($vehmakes)){
$output .= '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>/n';
};

echo $output;
```

Thanks!

Comment: i would try to turn on mysql caching. take a look at this http://theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php to get a better idea

Comment: You should look into memcached or redis. But your provider may not offer those. If you don't have access to those look at file caching with something like [phpFastCache](http://www.phpfastcache.com/) or any other file cache library.

Comment: You should take a look to Doctrine caching system for APC or Xcache to get some best practices. Varnish is useful too as a HTTP cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would just write to a flat file a comma separated list of makes for the given year and just check if the file exists before making your db query. you could perhaps set a timestamp in the future in the text file and check if this has expired if so create a new cache file overwriting the old.

```
if(file_exists($_POST['year'].'.txt'))
{
 // the file exists
 $select_options = explode(",",file_get_contents($_POST['year'].'.txt'));
// loop through the array for your options
}
else
{
 // make your db query
}
```

Comment: Never thought of that. Would I keep said flat file in the same folder as the php file with this code in it? And do I just replace '.txt' with the file name I chose?

Comment: you could store it anywhere you like you could have a dedicated cache dir and yes you could name it anything csv, xml, json, txt anything

Comment: If you want to use a file as a cache, don't forget to develop a script to refresh it. For example every 3600 seconds one user will refresh the cache file for others. So , one user will load data for others. You should store your cache files in a specific folder and setup a custom chmod (chmod -R 777).